# Tomcat Guacamole IPv6 locahost on Remote host

Tags: tomcat, catalina

I've successfully installed and configured guacamole 1.5.2 in Tomcat 9.0.78 and I can login to the entire system. From guacamole, after I've accessed a remote pc, for example via ssh, in the **User** -> **Settings** -> **History** in the column **Remote Host** I see the address 0:0:..:1, instead of the real remote address.

Furthermore by checking the *Catalina.log*, I see that for the user logged, I've two addresses, like for example `..... - User test successfully authenticated from [192.168.15.56,0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]`

My question is, how can I show in the **Remote Host** the first address instead of the IPv6 loopback address? Is there any particular settings to set in Tomcat?

Comment: I've solved the issue. In short word in the file ${TOMCAT_PATH}/conf/server.xml, it must be add between <host> the following

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" internalProxies="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />

Previously I had the same, but InternalProxies was set to 127.0.0.1.
Btw, Thank you so much

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are welcome to post and accept your own Answer to your own Question.